# How to use multiple Comparators on a Map and value properties with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a Map and need to sort the Key based on multiple conditions. How to achieve this using Java 8 Comparator and Stream?

```
class MyObject {
    private Set<Objects> setOfStuff;
    public Set<Objects> getSetOfStuff(){
        return listOfStuff;
    }
    public int countStuff(){
        return listOfStuff.size();
    }
}

Map<String, List<MyObject> needsSorting = new HashMap<>();
needsSorting.put("Monday", createSetOfObj());
needsSorting.put("Wednesday", createSetOfObj());
needsSorting.put("Thursday", createSetOfObj());

Set<MyObject> createSetOfObj() {
...
    return list;
}

Map<String, Set<MyObject>> sortedResult = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

1. Sort on Key, alphabetically
2. Sort key based on size of `List<MyObject>`
3. Sort Key based on size of the largest `MyObject countStuff();`

if not, it there a better approach?

**Update 1:**

I think I have 1 & 2 done. Just not sure about how to do 3.

```
Comparator<Entry<String, List<MyObject>>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, List<MyObject>>::getKey)
            .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size());
```

**Update 2:**

This seems to be producing the comparison I needed. I added a countStuff for easy size access.

```
Comparator<Entry<String, Set<MyObject>>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, Set<MyObject>>::getKey)
            .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size())
            .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(MyObject::countStuff).max(Integer::max).get());
```

Comment: Can you clarify what `List<MyObject>.getListOfStuff()` is supposed to do? Could it be rewritten, for example, as `list.stream().filter(...).count()` where `list` is of type `List<MyObject>`?

Comment: So, you want to sort a map by a complex sort condition, first by the key, then by the value attributes (list size, largest)?  Given that the original map is a `HashMap`, the keys must be unique; they can never be equal, so there will never be a need to check secondary sorting conditions.

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, Set<MyObject>>::getKey` => `Entry::comparingByKey`

Comment: `.max(Integer::max)` will definitely *not* do what you intent. You could do either `.max(Comparator.naturalOrder())` or `.reduce(Integer::max))`, but don’t mix them up. But anyway, it’s simpler and potentially more efficient to use `e.getValue().stream() .mapToInt(MyObject::countStuff).max().getAsInt()` instead.

Comment: Instead of `Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, Set<MyObject>>::getKey)` you can also use `Map.Entry.<String, Set<MyObject>>comparingByKey()`

Answer (score 1):

The HashMap is not ideal for sorting, you could use a `TreeMap` instead, and pass your comparator to the constructor:

```
SortedMap<String, List<MyObject>> sorted = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```

Edit : the comparator only works for keys not values